# How do I compare regions in the same file?

Tags: ediff

[`ediff`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/ediff/) allows comparing files, buffers, and regions in different buffers.
However, it does not let one compare sections in the same buffer.

Until now I used `isearch` for that: <kbd>C-s</kbd> at the beginning of the 1st identical section, the beginning of the second section is highlighted, then <kbd>C-w</kbd> to increase the search string until the second section no longer match.

Today I got `Too many words` error after several <kbd>C-w</kbd>.

So, what do people use these days to compare sections of the same buffer?

(yes, I can copy one of the sections into a throwaway buffer, but this is ugly).

Comment: ediff-regions-wordwise can work for two regions in the same buffer.

Comment: You could also use `clone-indirect-buffer-other-window` (C-x 4 c) and then narrow the two buffers (C-x n n) and use `ediff` on the two narrowed buffers

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `ediff-regions-wordwise`. It prompts you for two buffers, and then for two regions. The buffers can be the same.

Comment: This is simple to use (emacs provides guidance) and works. If your environment catches `C-M-c` key combination, then you can us the old trick of replacing Meta with a previous Escape. This becomes : `Esc C-c`.

Comment: https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CompareRegions also mentions `ediff-regions-linewise`.

Comment: How to actually choose the regions? C-Spc doesn't seem to be it?

Comment: Ah there's a box that's supposed to pop up, saying something like "hit C-M-spc when done" (I forgot the exact key now), but because of some bug in Aquamacs(?) wasn't showing up properly.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote `smerge-makeup-conflict` for similar uses.  Admittedly, it's not polished but I find it does the job (when you can modify the buffer):

- C-SPC at the beginning of the first part,
- C-SPC at the beginning of the second (which should be after the end of the first, and ideally close to it),
- then move to the end of the second part and do `M-x smerge-makeup-conflict`.

At that point you're in `smerge-mode` and you can use its functionality to compare (I typically mostly rely on `smerge-refine`).

Answer (score 1):

One thing I sometimes use for this is command `compare-windows` (repeated).  It compares the text in two windows, starting at point.

> Compare text in current window with text in next window.
>       Compares the text starting at point in each window,
>       moving over text in each one as far as they match.
>
> This command pushes the mark in each window
>       at the prior location of point in that window.
>       If both windows display the same buffer,
>       the mark is pushed twice in that buffer:
>       first in the other window, then in the selected window.
>
> A prefix arg means reverse the value of variable
>       `compare-ignore-whitespace`.  If `compare-ignore-whitespace` is
>       nil, then a prefix arg means ignore changes in whitespace.  If
>       `compare-ignore-whitespace` is non-nil, then a prefix arg means
>       don't ignore changes in whitespace.  The variable
>       `compare-windows-whitespace` controls how whitespace is skipped.
>       If `compare-ignore-case` is non-nil, changes in case are also
>       ignored.
>
> If `compare-windows-sync` is non-nil, then successive calls of
>       this command work in interlaced mode:
>       on first call it advances points to the next difference,
>       on second call it synchronizes points by skipping the difference,
>       on third call it again advances points to the next difference and so on.

(Another thing you can do is, as you said, to create another, throwaway, buffer, copy the content, and compare the two buffers.  Or use an indirect buffer, as @fredtantini suggested.)