# Is it necessary to save buffers as files in order to use command highlight-compare-buffer?

Tags: buffers, files, highlighting, ediff, save

Based on a nice comment from @[Drew](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/105/drew) on this [previous question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/18369/how-do-i-compare-regions-in-the-same-file), I tried to use the command `highlight-compare-buffers` (although he did not mention exactly this comment).

My first attempt was actually using ediff. But that attempt failed because I would need to ask for help which is bound to `?` and I am having a hard time with `?` on an American keyboard with Brazilian Portuguese input (see [the previous question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/72953/why-i-cant-type-things-such-as-and-in-emacs-with-my-macos-running-brazi)).

Since buffers and files can be different things and since the command explicitly mentions buffers on the name (instead of files), I was surprised that I only managed to make it work after saving the two buffers as files...

Emacs kept asking:

> Save buffer tweaked? (y or n) n

> Can’t find file: ~/projects/balance/src/app/components/report-total-view-maker-tb

Until the point that I hit `y`....

Is there something that I could have done to trigger this behavior?

Is it really necessary to save the new buffer as a file?

I would rather keep them just as buffers... This is a handy command that I haven't been using!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not too sure what you're asking, but `C-h f highlight-compare-buffers` says this, in part:

> If either buffer is **modified and is visiting a file**, you are prompted
> to save the file.
>
> Unless the buffer is unmodified and visiting a file, the buffer is
> written to a temporary file for comparison.

Does that help with your question at all?